# footmisc package - remove star from footnote symbols

Tags: formatting, footnotes, footmisc

I'm using `footmisc` package for handling footnotes. I want to remove the star (*) from the symbol list?

I tried all the combination of

```
\DefineFNsymbols*{}{}
```

and

```
\setfnsymbol{}
```

except the correct one!:)

Could someone be so kind to point me to the correct command?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you only want to remove the `*` from the list of used symbols or not have any symbols at all? Your code shown suggest more the latter.

Comment: No, just *. I just showed the commands I was trying to use!

Comment: I see. In such cases either write the macro without `{}` or with `{...}` instead. Note that you can also format code inline in posts here using backticks `\``.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The manual of `footmisc` states that the default symbol list is defined as:

```
\DefineFNsymbols*{lamport}[math]{*\dagger\ddagger\S\P\|{**}{\dagger\dagger}{\ddagger\ddagger}}
```

and then set using:

```
\setfnsymbol{lamport}
```

So, if you only want to remove the `*` (and maybe `**`) you can use:

```
\DefineFNsymbols*{lamportnostar}[math]{\dagger\ddagger\S\P\|{\dagger\dagger}{\ddagger\ddagger}}
\setfnsymbol{lamportnostar}
```

Otherwise use:

```
\DefineFNsymbols*{mysymbols}[math]{<some symbols>}
\setfnsymbol{mysymbols}
```

Note: The `math` option ensures that the symbol are used in math-mode.

Comment: I can't compile
`\documentclass[pdftex, a4paper, numbers=noendperiod]{scrbook}


    \usepackage[perpage,symbol*]{footmisc}

    \DefineFNsymbols*{lamportnostar}{\dagger\ddagger\S\P\|{\dagger\dagger}{\ddagger\ddagger}}
\setfnsymbol{lamportnostar}


    \begin{document}
        ciao\footnote{means hello.} 
    \end{document}
`

Comment: @Pie86: I had a look on it and added the required `math` option which fixes this. The manual seems to be inaccurate at one point (no `[math]`) which caused this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[perpage,para]{footmisc}

\usepackage{alphalph}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\fnsymbolsingle}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \ifcase#1%
%    \or *%
    \or \dagger
    \or \ddagger
    \or \mathsection
    \or \mathparagraph
    \else
      \@ctrerr
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
\newalphalph{\fnsymbolmult}[mult]{\fnsymbolsingle}{}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{%
  \fnsymbolmult{\value{footnote}}%
}


%\renewcommand\thefootnote{\itshape\arabic{footnote}}

\begin{document}

text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.} text\footnote{Third footnote.} text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.} text\footnote{Third footnote.} text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.} text\footnote{Third footnote.}

text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.} text\footnote{Third footnote.} text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.} text\footnote{Third footnote.} text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.} text\footnote{Third footnote.}

text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.} text\footnote{Third footnote.} text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.} text\footnote{Third footnote.} text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.} text\footnote{Third footnote.}
\clearpage
text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.} text\footnote{Third footnote.} text\footnote{First footnote.} text\footnote{Second footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you indent your code by four spaces (or select it and hit the {} button), it formats up nicely as above.

Answer (score 0):

The manual omits the `[math]` option to the `\DefineFNsymbols*` definition. This is what I've been calling in my preamble, moving the star later in the sequence, and naming the sequence "dagnabbit":

```
\usepackage[symbol, perpage, bottom]{footmisc}
\DefineFNsymbols*{dagnabbit}[math]{\dagger\ddagger\S\P\|{*}{**}{\dagger\dagger}{\ddagger\ddagger}}
\setfnsymbol{dagnabbit}
```