# How to make the footnote starting from \dag?

Tags: footnotes, counters

The default sequence of symbol `footnote` is `*,\dag,\ddag,...` How can I make the footnote starting from `\dag`, i.e., the sequence `\dag,\ddag,...`? Thanks in advance. (I have the package `\usepackage[perpage,symbol]{footmisc}`). My question is answered in the link: [footmisc package - remove star from footnote symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16239/footmisc-package-remove-star-from-footnote-symbols)

Comment: `\setcounter{footnote}{1}`.  Then, when `\footnote` is invoked, it gets automatically incremented to `2`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for your comment. I am failed because of the package `\usepackage[perpage,symbol]{footmisc}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am sorry for the old question, now I update it. I use the symbol footnote, not the arabic one in fact.

Comment: Perhaps this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36090/alternative-symbol-sets-for-footnote-marks provides a solution for you

Comment: You can define your own set of symbols with `\DefineFNSymbols{…}`. See § 1.7 of the documentation.